# IIS7 splash screen shows but individual app is inaccessible

Tags: iis-7, acl

The IIS7 splash screen displays when I type `http://myservername` into the browser address bar. The Default Web Site is operational.  However, when I create a virtual directory whose physical path is `inetpub/wwwroot/myappfolder`, convert to application choosing an app pool for it (4.x) and enabling anonymous authentication (with app pool identity), and then upload the files to the physical path , there's an error screen when I type `http://myservername/myappname/foo.htm` into the browser address bar. Possible causes for the error are that required permissions are missing. I have given read access to `inetpub/wwwroot/myappfolder` to IIS_IUSRS and IUSR.  What step(s) am I missing? Is firewall configuration also necessary to get web apps to work? Windows Server 2008R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worker process doesn't work in the context of the users you mentioned. It will be "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" if you are using default app pool. For details check section "Securing Resources" of [this article](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).